# apache mina FTPS on remote requets not works

Tags: apache-mina

For the **Apache MINA FTP Server SSL FILTER configuration** : I tried everything and I  read more than 50 posts on stackoverflow to find the error. But still no solution.

Problem Is that, 
**When the SSL Filter Enabled** for the Apache MINA FTP, it is working on server side and at the Server **Locally FileZilla Client Can Access to server over implicitSSL** it works without problem.

I allowed the 21 port and passive ports over firewall for all ips.

**But when the remote client** wants to access to the server,  SERVER getting request but **session.write not works** then MINA can not switch to USER exec, **SO REMOTE client can not c**onnect FTP server.

**But when I disable implicitSSL** mode on SERVER side, CLIENT can connect . SO,  without SSL, Client Connect Remote SERVER. It is tricky But WHY,  what is the problem.

- If the problem is firewall , why the client connects **when I disable implicitSSL**.
- If the CODE is or configuration is the problem, **WHEN I enable implicitSSL** =true, **WHY local SERVER filezilla application can connect** to server over implicitSSL.

**

> Please help.

**